# Electric dipole approximation for perturbation: What is this symbol and how was it part of this derivation?

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics, hamiltonian, polarization, dipole

I'm reading electrodynamics physics notes that describe the polarization of a medium. The notes describe the active atoms as having two levels $a$ and $b$, separated by energy $\hbar \omega$ and represented by a density matrix $\rho$. The atoms are stationary.

The equation of motion of the density matrix is

$$\dot{\rho} = -i[H, \rho] - \dfrac{1}{2}\left(\Gamma \rho + \rho \Gamma \right) + \lambda,$$

where

$$\rho = \begin{bmatrix} \rho_{aa} & \rho_{ab} \\ \rho_{ba} & \rho_{bb} \end{bmatrix}, \ \ \ \ \ H = \begin{bmatrix} W_{a} & V \\ V & W_{b} \end{bmatrix}, \\ \Gamma = \begin{bmatrix} \gamma_{a} & 0 \\ 0 & \gamma_{b} \end{bmatrix}, \ \ \ \ \ \lambda = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_{a} & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_{b} \end{bmatrix}$$

The notes then state that the perturbation Hamiltonian is $\hbar V$, and the unperturbed energies of the levels are $\hbar W_a$ and $\hbar W_b$. Furthermore, the two levels decay with damping constants $\gamma_a$ and $\gamma_b$, and are populated by pumping at rates $\lambda_a$ and $\lambda_b$.

Therefore, using the Fourier expansion of the electric field $E(z, t) = \sum\limits_n A_n(t) u_n(z)$, where $u_n(z) = \sin(k_n z)$ and $k_n = \dfrac{n \pi}{L}$, the notes claim that the electric dipole approximation for the perturbation becomes

[image]

I've included the image of the equation because I don't actually understand what that symbol between $A(t)$ and $u(z)$ is (I can't find it as a LaTeX symbol, and I've never seen it before). What is this symbol and how was it part of this derivation?

---

Relevant: [Quantum Mechanical Electric Dipole Hamiltonian](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Time_Dependent_Quantum_Mechanics_and_Spectroscopy_(Tokmakoff)/07%3A_Interaction_of_Light_and_Matter/7.03%3A_Quantum_Mechanical_Electric_Dipole_Hamiltonian)

$$V(t) = - \left( \sum_j \dfrac{q_j}{m_j} \left( \hat{\epsilon} \cdot \hat{p}_j \right) \right) \dfrac{E_0}{\omega} \sin(\omega t) \tag{7.3.13}$$

Comment: It looks like the symbol for the [Weierstrass *p*-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_elliptic_function), but I have no idea what it means in this context.  In LaTeX it's `\wp`, which gives $\wp$.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Ahh, thanks for that. My best guess is that it's a catch-all constant for a bunch of other constants that come along in the derivation, but I'm not sure. If it is a catch-all constant, then it's a bit weird that it's written as sitting between the $A(t)$ and $u(z)$, rather than out front.

Comment: There is no such symbol that I can see in the linked page…

Comment: @ZeroTheHero The one I linked? That's not the source – it's just some material that covers the theory of electric dipole Hamiltonians.

Comment: well it’s difficult to tell without context but I’ve see this symbol used for the polarization vector, which is related to the microscopic dipole moment.

Comment: You should provide the notes themselves if possible, otherwise we don't have much context to go on.

Comment: @Triatticus I transcribed the notes into my post.

Comment: If we look at the relevant article I provided in my post, we can see that 7.3.13 is remarkably similar to what I've got. So that's why I wonder if the $\wp$ symbol is just a catch-all for some constants (and the summation symbol from the expansion).

Comment: I mean are they available as a PDF online and if so can the link to the full notes be provided.

Comment: @Triatticus They were provided to me through private means, so I don't think / know if they're publicly available.

Comment: $\wp$ may be referring to a polarization operator that has different susceptibility under electric fields with different wavenumbers.

Comment: It is extremely hard to give a good answer to this without seeing the original lecture notes. The picture of the equation you provided, which you're calling the "electric dipole approximation for the perturbation", was certainly not derived starting from the Hamiltonian you provided. The electric dipole approximation is detailed in the article you linked. It seems like your notes simply invoked the electric dipole approximation, with the assumption that the audience knows what it is.

Comment: By the way, that small symbol definitely represents the dipole moment operator, which @akhmeteli pointed out. That is essentially what the dipole approximation is - that the interaction potential only couples to the dipole moment of the state, via the dipole moment operator.

Comment: @ArturodonJuan Ok, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Take a look at [this article](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qm/lectures/node79.html) for another (equivalent) derivation of the electric dipole approximation. The starting point is basically the assumption that the electric field doesn't vary much over the extent of the atom. The ultimate expression you land on is right-most side of equation (890) in the article I just linked, where only the position operator $\vec x$ appears in the matrix element of the perturbation.

Comment: @ArturodonJuan Ok, thanks again.

Comment: I don't know how to say this without sounding rude, but I feel like recently you've been asking a lot of questions because you've been spending time reading particularly unclear, unpolished sets of lecture notes. I spent a lot of time doing just that in college, because I simply read whatever the professors gave me, but in reality everything is covered much better in standard books...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Energy of a dipole $p$ is minus $p$ times electric field (https://unlcms.unl.edu/cas/physics/tsymbal/teaching/EM-913/section4-Electrostatics.pdf), so your symbol probably denotes the electric dipole moment (which is closely related to polarization, as @ZeroTheHero suggested).

EDIT (Jan 20, 2022) Looks like the derivation of the energy of an electric dipole in the electric field is given in [Journal of Modern Optics (2004)
vol. 51, no. 8, 1137–114](http://www.hajim.rochester.edu/optics/sites/boyd/archive/papers/Boyd_JMO_04.pdf), Section 2, so the symbol is indeed the electric dipole moment.

Comment: I looked through the document, but I don't see anything that resembles $V(t) = - A(t) \wp \sin(k_n z) / \hbar$. Which part of section 2 is this?

Comment: @ThePointer: They derive the interaction Hamiltonian in the form $-d\cdot E$ and they pretty much get it in (2.10). Note that in your case $E=A(t)u(z)$, and $V(t)$ is the interaction Hamiltonian (up to a constant).

Comment: So their $e$ is basically my $\wp$? And I'm assuming $e$ contains the $\dfrac{1}{\hbar}$ factor in mine? What is the $\dfrac{\pi^2}{2m}$ in theirs? This term seems to be absent in mine.

Comment: No, your ℘ is their $e r$. And their $\pi^2/2m$ is not relevant, it's kinetic energy. As for $\hbar$, your interaction Hamiltonian is $\hbar V$.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thanks for taking the time to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Forming my comments into an answer.

The odd symbol you're looking at is most certainly the (negative of the) electric dipole moment of an individual atom, or the electric dipole moment density of the uniform gas. I've never seen that symbol used before, so it's quite odd the author didn't clearly state what this symbol meant.

You're wondering how to derive the electric dipole approximation, which is essentially the equation in that picture, from the equations up above (the evolution equation for the density matrix, and the electric field Fourier decomposition). However, the dipole approximation is a separately derived approximation, and by itself has nothing to do with those equations. The author of those lecture notes is presumably using the dipole approximation as a tool to write a simplified evolution equation for $\rho$.